# How does the certificate of 'Require SSL' in IIS relate to the HTTPS certificate for website binding?

Tags: security, ssl, iis, https

I'm trying to figure out client certificate authentication in IIS (10).

I have a website that I want to use only with SSL/HTTPS and only authorized clients are allowed to access.

I have a COMODO SSL certificate that I bought and I'm using to provide HTTPS access. When I enable Require SSL and check 'Require' I get a prompt when visiting the site in the browser.

My question is how can I generate certificates for this prompt. If I download the certificate I use for HTTPS in the binding to my computer and select that in the browser I get access. Not only that but If I select other COMODO certificates that I use for other websites in IIS on the server I get access as well.

I figured out it has something to do with the certificate authority..but I can't figure out the steps to completely create a client certificate that works with Require SSL while using a generic (comodo) https binding cert.

Is the SSL cert I use for the https binding always the same as the client auth. cert? Or atleast the same CA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So essentially what we have is mutual authentication , so the server identifies the client by using the certificate and both the client and the server certificate have a common trust in place in this case it is the certificate issuer i.e. COMODO

Now you have some options ( though i am not sure why you want the user to present the certificate but that is a different discussion all together )

1. Setup up your own CA in the intranet and integrate it with AD and provide the users with individual certificates from the same CA.

Or

2. Alternately if you want to use the COMODO ceritificate , the users can generate there own certificate from this link https://www.comodo.com/home/email-security/free-email-certificate.php